# how can i use get the columns data when looking through them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets, each with 1 only 1 table at various widths and heights.

I am trying to achive:
once user have selected sheet via combobox, (this works)
then i can list the headers from the table on that sheet.

my possible solution idea:
My idea was to list the table headers in a combobox on a userform.

1. i count columns on selected sheet,  works
2. for loop through the columns to grab the header name from each and stack into combobox.list,

code:

```
Private Sub chcSite_Change()
Dim siteSheet As String
siteSheet = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.chcSite.Value, Worksheets("Overview").Range("SiteTable"), 2, False)

Me.chcRange.Enabled = True  ' enables combobox for headers list

Dim COLS As Integer
COLS = Worksheets(siteSheet).ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For i = 1 To COLS   
    If Worksheets(siteSheet).Cells(Columns(i), 1) = "" Then Exit For   ' if header is empty = also end of table cols.
    MsgBox Worksheets(siteSheet).Cells(Columns(i), 1)  ' debug to see what it returns.

Next i


'Me.chcRange.List = Worksheets(siteSheet).ListObjects(1).ColumnHeads ' random test of columnheads

End Sub
```

as you can see i was exspecting Worksheets(siteSheet).Cells(Columns(i), 1) to return something, but it appears it is only a pointer/selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might benefit from reading [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

For example to get the 3rd heading of a table use

```
.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange(3)
```

The ListObject has its own row/column numbering and may be different from the sheets row/column numbering.

It should look something like this:

```
Dim i As Long 'always use Long
'i = 1 not needed

For i = 1 To COLS   
    ' v-- this part is not needed …
    If Worksheets(siteSheet).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange(i) = "" Then 
        Exit For   ' if header is empty = also end of table cols.
    End If
    ' ^-- … because headers of ListObjects can not be empty by definition.
    '       And HeaderRowRange can only access the headers of the ListObjects.

    MsgBox Worksheets(siteSheet).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange(i)  ' debug to see what it returns.
Next i
```

So you can shorten it to:

```
Dim i As Long 
For i = 1 To COLS   
    MsgBox Worksheets(siteSheet).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange(i)  ' debug to see what it returns.
Next i
```

---

Note that `Cells(Columns(i), 1)` could not work because eg `Columns(2)` references the complete column B (it is a range representing the full column 2) and `Cells` needs a row/column number like `Cells(row, column)`.